# SurfaceView doesn't get repainted

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am developing a small test game on android. I use a SurfaceView to draw on a Canvas.

Here comes my problem: Only one frame is shown, but `listener.draw(..)` gets called as it should, **so my game is a still image**.

A thread calls `draw(..)` every iteration, but the screen doesn't update.

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(alive) { // to prevent drawing if view exists but surface isn't created
            // ...

            final int savedState = canvas.save();

            try {
                canvas.clipRect(leftPadding, topPadding, leftPadding + finalWidth, topPadding + finalHeight);
                canvas.translate(leftPadding, topPadding);
                canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

                if(listener != null)
                    listener.draw(this, canvas);
            } finally {
                canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
            }
        }
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        alive = true;

        while(alive) {
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

            long currentFrameStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            deltaFrameTime = currentFrameStart - lastFrameStart;
            lastFrameStart = currentFrameStart;

            listener.update(this, deltaFrameTime);

            Canvas canvas = null;

            try {
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

                synchronized(holder) {
                    draw(canvas);
                }
            } finally {
                if(canvas != null) {
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling some more hours gave me a solution:

http://danielnadeau.blogspot.de/2012/01/android-canvas-beginners-tutorial.html

instead of

```
try {
    canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

    synchronized(holder) {
        draw(canvas);
    }
} finally {
    if(canvas != null) {
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

I now use

```
try {
    canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

    synchronized(holder) {
        postInvalidate();
    }
} finally {
    if(canvas != null) {
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm currently working on something similar, and got it to work using your `postInvalidate()` solution, but I'm not sure if using this, you're "asking" the Android framework to redraw your view. That's not what I'm looking for (I need quick redrawing), and thus I was using the `onDraw()`method, but it draws me nothing.... I'm getting desperate and I don't really know where's the problem because the code inside `onDraw()`is ran, but the result doesn't seem to be "rendered" :l

Comment: @Jorge33212 I don't really remember, but I think that's the same issue I had. I'm not really experienced in Android development, so there's only a little chance I can help, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `invalidate()` ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6755993/2945214

Comment: Yes and no, I tried that, but this is only possible if you call it on the UiThread, but my draw and update thread is another one. I saw many tutorials using the same method I used or with a little change (calling `onDraw(..)` instead of `draw(..)` which is not recommended). Both didn't work.